# Error 502 Bad Gateway while my CPU and RAM are at 50%

Tags: cpu, nginx, gateway

For a while, my server has been returning 502 Bad Gateway errors randomly during the day. Sometimes we have the same traffic and everything is fine, other times it causes 502 errors. I have a web traffic of about 50r/s and here is the CPU and RAM usage attached.

I'm using PHP FPM 7.4 with config:

```
pm.max_childrens = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
```

VPS Specs:

```
8 vCore
16GB Ram
```

CPU & Ram Usage:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello. Where are these 502 errors coming from, a web browser? What version of Ubuntu are you using? More details needed.

Comment: Do you mean HTTP return code `502 Bad Gateway - The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.`? If yes, please edit that information into your question.

Comment: @DougSmythies it's only a 502 error of nginx, with written "502 - Bad Gateway"

Comment: @David These errors come only from the browser. If I try to change mysql values from the ssh, nothing lags. However, and this is what I don't understand, is that from my web browser, I get 502 errors. No lag detected whether it is machine/ftp/change mysql value from ssh...

Comment: I tried to change the pm.max_children of php-fpm. Result, no more lags except that mysql returns me errors 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' after one minute on all requests.